# Visual Studio 2010 - Schema Compare - Specify Database (Security) Schema

Tags: database, visual-studio, schema-compare

I am using Visual Studio 2010's database functionality to compare database schemas. I am comparing database#1 and database#2. I would like to compare only only objects within the same security schema within my databases (dbo, myschemaname, etc.) rather than comparing all objects within that database but I cannot figure out how to do so. Does anyone have any way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no inbuilt way to filter the examined objects based on name, only by type.  Gosh, that'd be a nice feature to have -- you should file a feature enhancement request with Microsoft. :-)

The only solution I can think of -- and I'm hesitant to even call it that -- would be to create separate logins on both servers that only have access to specific schemas.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have indeed filed an enhancement request on Connect (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/587557/schema-data-comparison-filter-by-security-schema)

Answer (score -3):

Create two other databases, db1c and db2c, which only contain the objects with the schemas you want to compare.