# Visual Studio 2012 - Schema Compare

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, schema, compare

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to compare my development database project with an existing databases. The existing database have some customized tables, stored procedures and functions, that I want them to be ignored.

My first thought is using Security Schemas, and i found this workarround:
[Visual Studio 2010 - Schema Compare - Specify Database (Security) Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249274/visual-studio-2010-schema-compare-specify-database-security-schema)

Is there any other solution?

Is there a way to automatize a task to generate a scripts with the differences? Something like the TFS automatic builds?

Answer (score 1):

It's obviously been a couple of months since you asked this, but as far as I'm aware this isn't yet possible with schema compare / SSDT.

This sort of functionality is possible with third party tools such as redgates Sql Compare (by using filters), but I know that's not the question you asked.

If you have found out how to do it in the meantime, please let me know! :)

Comment: By a coincidence we've very recently added SSDT database project support into SQL Compare so it turns out that your answer is spot on. SQL Compare can both read and write to a database project structure. Filters will also work.